# Show that every extension in $\mathbb{C}$, of degree $2$, is normal.

Tags: field-theory

Show that every extension in $\mathbb{C}$, of degree $2$, is normal.

I know to prove this I need to show that there is a splitting field for each extension and then I am done. I have been googling as well but everywhere I see the proofs it talks about characterize of a field, which I don't want to use. Can I get some assistance?

Comment: Do you mean degree $2$ extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$? In that case, here's a helpful fact: all degree $2$ extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ are of the form $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$, where $d$ is a square-free integer.

Comment: Yes I do. So $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ contains both roots of the minimal polynomial $x^2-d$. Hence I am done? Seems to simple to me

Comment: That's all there is to it. You might want to prove that fact about degree $2$ extensions though as part of the problem.

Comment: You see the problem seems to trivial to me that is why I have had a hard time formally writing it up

Comment: @UsernameUnknown Your proof should most likely use the quadratic formula.  It is false, for example, in characteristic $2$.